# Issue with Headers and Global Variable

Tags: c++, global-variables, header-files, precompiled-headers

So I'm having an issue with declaring a global variable (in the header) and using it. I've done some reading on header files and how they work, but I can't understand why my code isn't working.

Here's what I have (in a simplified manner):

**Main:**

```
// main.cpp

#include "source.hpp"

int main()
{
    return variable;
}
```

**Source:**

```
// source.cpp

#include "source.hpp"

variable = 17;
```

**Header:**

```
// source.hpp

#ifndef __SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__
#define __SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__

extern int variable;

#endif  // __SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__
```

I've tried with and without *extern* in the header file.
I get this error when I try to (compile in the source):
*'variable' does not name a type*
What am I not understanding properly?

Also, when I declare the same variable in *main.cpp*, the compiler does throw back an error about 'redefining' the variable. Why is that?

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__SOURCE_HPP_INCLUDED__`) and names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In source.cpp you need to **define** the variable:

```
int variable = 17;
```

Comment: That solved it! So is true that I always need to re-define the variable somewhere else (such as the source), even though I already defined it in the header?

Comment: @MaxJacob: `extern int i;` is a **declaration**, `int i;` is a definition. C++ has a single-definition rule. You cannot define a symbol more than once.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you for the clarification!